# Query regarding pooled quota waiting list ticket on Indian Railways

Tags: trains, indian-railways

I have booked a ticket from Rajkot to Delhi in Porbander Motihari express as on 19.12.14 but out of the 5 passengers, 4 have been shown as confirmed and 1 in pooled quota waiting list.

So whether the 5th passenger is allowed to travel with us by sharing our seat even if that seat of pooled quota in our ticket of 5 passengers is not confirmed.

Answer (score 5):

From the tag and the name of the quota I infer it is Indian Railways.  The short answer is Yes, the fifth passenger is allowed to travel with you.  This rule does have some exceptions like for travel in Rajadhani /Shatapdi Express this would not be applicable but for the trains you indicated it is allowed.

The rules relating to this are shown on the [Indian Rails website](https://www.services.irctc.co.in/beta_htmls/Waitlisted_E-Ticket.html)

> Name of the passengers whose names are partly confirmed/partly waitlist or partly RAC/partly waitlist, their names shall appear in charts including the waitlist passengers.

So once name is in chart they can board the train and travel with their party, however the TTE is bound to allot them a berth after allotting berths to all other confirmed passengers and RAC passengers.